# error while read log file with json.loads in python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have two different log files and i am able to read log file 1 with using method json.loads method but getting error**(json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1))** while using the same method on log file 2. Please find below mentioned sample log file 1, log file 2 data and sample code that i am using. The difference i observed between both logs are few extra char as "[DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3]" before '{' bracket and extra exception log after '}' bracket. I also tried to split line and remove extra spaces and got success but not able to remove error. Please suggest how to read log file 2 by using same json.loads method. Thanx in advance.
Below is sample code1 that i am using on both file 1 and file 2 from which i am getting success result for file 1 but error on file two.

code1:

```
inputfile ='home/msLog-'+todaydate+'.0.log'
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x = json.loads(line)
        msd = x['msisdn']
        if msd != 'NA':
            msd = x['msisdn']
```

Below is sample code 2 that i am using only on file 2 and still getting same error as code 1

```
inputfile ='home/msLog-'+todaydate+'.0.log'
with open(inputfile, 'r') as f:
#log = Path(inputfile).read_text()
    #f = [x for x in f.split('}') if x]
    #line = " "
#for line in log.split('\n'):
    for line in f:
        line = [x for x in line.split('{}') if x]
        line = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in line])
        line = re.sub('\s+', '', line)
#        print(line)
        x = json.dumps(line)
        x = json.loads(x)
        print(x)
        msd = x["msisdn"]
```

Please also find below sample log file 1 and log file 2

**Log file 1:**

{"methodName":"offlineNotifQueueListener()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.jms.listener.impl.ActiveMqListener","text":"Processing Offline request","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_67f32b84-5afb-4e26-8c13-829e2b3e3148","orgTransactionID":"302736862296641002","msisdn":"22966410021","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-05-01T13:15:20+0100","state":"ENTERED" {"methodName":"addNotificationText()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.notification.impl.MSProductNotificationImpl","text":"Evaluating notification for product : 1399","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_67f32b84-5afb-4e26-8c13-829e2b3e3148","orgTransactionID":"302736862296641002","msisdn":"22966410021","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-05-01T13:15:20+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"} {"methodName":"getValueFromAIR()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.templateparam.impl.TemplateParamServiceImpl","text":"Evaluating parameter --\u003e ${OFFER_123089_VALUE}","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_67f32b84-5afb-4e26-8c13-829e2b3e3148","orgTransactionID":"302736862296641002","msisdn":"22966410021","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-05-01T13:15:21+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"}

**Log file 2:**

2020-05-01 13:15:21:015 | INFO [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3] {"methodName":"executeCommand","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.service.templateparam.impl.TemplateParamServiceImpl","text":"Executing AIR command ---\u003e GetOffers","errorText":"NA","status":"NA","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_67f32b84-5afb-4e26-8c13-829e2b3e3148","orgTransactionID":"302736862296641002","msisdn":"22966410021","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"1399","transactionDateTime":"2020-05-01T13:15:21+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"} 2020-05-01 13:15:21:039 | ERROR [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3] {"methodName":"executeAction()","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.action.impl.MSNotificationAction","text":"Unable to send notification : ","errorText":"NA","status":"FAILURE","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_67f32b84-5afb-4e26-8c13-829e2b3e3148","orgTransactionID":"302736862296641002","msisdn":"22966410021","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"NA","transactionDateTime":"2020-05-01T13:15:21+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"} com.ericsson.ms.business.exception.NotificationFailedException: Notification Template not configured for languageId : 2 at com.ericsson.ms.business.service.notification.impl.MSProductNotificationImpl.addNotificationText(MSProductNotificationImpl.java:249) at com.ericsson.ms.business.service.notification.impl.MSProductNotificationImpl.addNotificationText(MSProductNotificationImpl.java:79) at com.ericsson.ms.business.action.impl.MSNotificationAction.executeAction(MSNotificationAction.java:46) at com.ericsson.ms.business.action.MSActionExecutorService.executeAction(MSActionExecutorService.java:53) at com.ericsson.ms.business.jms.listener.impl.ActiveMqListener.offlineNotifQueueListener(ActiveMqListener.java:64) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:104) at org.springframework.jms.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:69) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 2020-05-01 13:15:21:040 | ERROR [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3] {"methodName":"","className":"com.ericsson.ms.business.action.MSActionExecutorService","text":"Unable to execute category : Notification for msisdn : 22966410021","errorText":"NA","status":"FAILURE","requestID":"OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_67f32b84-5afb-4e26-8c13-829e2b3e3148","orgTransactionID":"302736862296641002","msisdn":"22966410021","action":"Notification","input":"pre_Adhoc","sourceChannel":"OFFLINE","product":"NA","transactionDateTime":"2020-05-01T13:15:21+0100","state":"IN_PROGRESS"} com.ericsson.ms.business.exception.MSCategoryFailedException: com.ericsson.ms.business.exception.NotificationFailedException: Notification Template not configured for languageId : 2 at com.ericsson.ms.business.action.impl.MSNotificationAction.executeAction(MSNotificationAction.java:53) at com.ericsson.ms.business.action.MSActionExecutorService.executeAction(MSActionExecutorService.java:53) at com.ericsson.ms.business.jms.listener.impl.ActiveMqListener.offlineNotifQueueListener(ActiveMqListener.java:64) at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor153.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

**Actual error that i am getting:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MSReport.py", line 51, in <module>
    x = json.loads(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`2020-05-01 13:15:21:015 | INFO [DefaultMessageListenerContainer-3]` in the beginning of log 2 is not json compliant. Remove it and you shall be fixed.
Worst case you could use parttern matching to only keep the part of the log that is contained in `{ }`

Comment: i cannot remove that line because it is part of log file.

Comment: Did you put your file content in a json validator eg https://jsonlint.com/ to check what are the json non compliance? Then it is a matter of filtering them out before calling `json.loads`